# Response From Django Rest Api Framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have created lots of `API's` list this using Django Rest Framework and it is working perfectly fine. But the issue i am facing is that when these `API's` are executed succesfully, then i am not getting `Response` like `status=true` or any response which says it executed successfully. Is there in-built function in `rest framework` or how can i do it to get success message.

```
# Add Trusty
class TrustyAddAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = TrustyRequest.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.TrustyAddSerialzer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]


# User Trusty Profile Update
class TrustyUserProfileUpdateAPIView(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.UserDetailSerialzer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
```

Comment: You will get **`2XX`** status code if the request succeeded. You could use the same to identify the status

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override the `get` and `post` method and in return you can send response as:

```
class UserList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.UserListSerialzer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def list(self, request):
        # Note the use of `get_queryset()` instead of `self.queryset` 
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        serializer = self.serializer_class(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(
                {
                    "result": serializer.data,
                    "message":"Testimonials Retrieved Successfully.",
                    "status" : True,
                }            
            )
```

Answer (score 2):

when the API is executed successfully, you should return a 200 response. This done in django like this:

```
return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

read more about HTTP [status code](https://httpstatuses.com/)